# Loading a large collection from MongoDB to Meteor makes pages slow

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am developing an app in Meteor for the first time. As seen in the documentation, I am loading my collections this way:

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection("items")
```

The `items` collection has more than a million documents and makes page loading very slow. How can I avoid this overhead?

Answer (score 2):

First remove the `autopublish` package from the console:

```
$ meteor remove autopublish
```

Otherwise all records will be published to all clients and 1M records will be very slow.

Second, create a publication that *filters* the collection to only publish those documents that are actually relevant to the current user in the current application context:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('myItems',function(){
  if ( this.userId ){
    return Items.find({ some query relevant to the user },
      {fields: { key1: 1, key2: 1, ... only relevant fields }});
  }
  this.ready();
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myItems');
```

Your query and list of relevant fields might vary by class of user. You can also have multiple *publications* on the same *collection* for different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection has millions of document, it very bad to have entire data loaded on front-end may it be any circumstances.

you should wisely use **PAGINATION**, as there are packages out there for pagination in meteor. But if you want to use pagination with simple Session variable handling (the variable keeps the "**skip**" value which is accessible at both client and server) with **aslagle:reactive-table** for better presentation, you can watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UivnTM1YA-I

After implementing this feature, you yourself will feel that loading entire data on UI is not feasible solution and pagination works without page refresh, asynchronously and reactively.